# Running a shell script on android device using adb

Tags: android, shell, adb

Manually, we can run:

```
adb shell
su
chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf &
```

However, we need to be able to run that from a bash script on the computer compiling the program.

I have tried:

```
adb shell "su
    && chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
    && export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
    && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
    && exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main /data/local/device.conf &"
```

But since we are entering the su shell, this does not work.

Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: In what sense does it "not work"?

Comment: The command ends up in the adb shell, and does not execute the commands after that. When you call su
the code I had would have made "su" run in adb shell
then not the next commands

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
adb shell "su -c '
chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0
&& export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
&& export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
&& exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main
    /data/local/device.conf &'"
```

It might be possible to simplify it, too:

```
adb shell "su -c '
chmod 666 /dev/graphics/fb0 &&
CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local
app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main
    /data/local/device.conf &'"
```

This is because you can set environment variables for one job just by prepending them on the line, rather than the export this, export that form.

Comment: [1] Killed su -c "
chmod 66...
the device is not recognized anymore! crashed still...