# GUI-less programming for Android as if it were an ordinary Linux system

Tags: android, android-activity, scripting, command-line-interface

I need to do some menial batch tasks on my phone, and I don't want to jump through all the hoops of making an "app" with a GUI and all that just to do them (the tasks are of the type you'd hack together in BASH in five minutes on a sane system). I can't seem to find any place on the net that explains how to simply make an ordinary program (in any language, but Java is OK if that eases interaction with Android) *with access to the Android API* that can simply be run by SSHing into the phone and running it as a normal process. No need for an APK package, no need for a GUI, no nothing. This should be the simplest thing in the world, but every example out there seems to be first and foremost concerned with making a GUI and working with Eclipse and the SDK instead of doing the basics first.

Any tips?

(I know this is probably borderline SuperUser, but then again, there's a programming question at the bottom: How do you make an ordinary (Java) program that can be run from the terminal on an Android phone and still use the API?)

Comment: I do think "making a GUI and working with Eclipse and the SDK" *are* the basics!

Comment: Writing the simplest code possible (i.e. text output), compiling it and running it from a terminal on the device must surely be called more basic.

Comment: For future reference: `dalvikvm` from CommonWare's answer does what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't seem to find any place on the net that explains how to simply make an ordinary program (in any language, but Java is OK if that eases interaction with Android) with access to the Android API that can simply be run by SSHing into the phone and running it as a normal process.

That's because it's not especially important to the bulk of Android users or developers.

> How do you make an ordinary (Java) program that can be run from the terminal on an Android phone and still use the API?

You are welcome to use the [Scripting Layer for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) to write some scripts, but you have limited access to the Android SDK, and they cannot "simply be run by SSHing into the phone". This is supported by the SL4A team.

You are welcome to experiment with [the `dalvikvm` command](http://www.milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/hello-world.html), though off the top of my head I do not recall whether or not it is available on production devices, and I do not know if it can "simply be run by SSHing into the phone". And, bear in mind that using this is completely unsupported.

You are welcome to write your own C/C++ code for ARM (or whatever CPU architecture your device runs). This "simply be run by SSHing into the phone" but has no access to the Android SDK.

> I still cannot believe that that kind of stuff isn't on the first page of every Android development introduction out there.

There are over 200 million users of Android devices. What percentage of those users do you think want to 
"make an ordinary program... with access to the Android API that can simply be run by SSHing into the phone and running it as a normal process"? 0.01%? 0.001%? My money is on 0.0001%.

The "first page of every Android development introduction out there" should be focused on stuff that matters to closer to 100% of the user base. You, of course, are welcome to build up your own site focused on this sort of thing, to cater to those users who are interested in creating these sorts of programs.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, and I don't want to turn this into an argument (especially against someone obviously more knowledgeable than me), but I'll make a comment. S4LA seems like a nice idea, but it also appears to be reinventing the wheel. Wouldn't it be nicer to just make the API accessible through, for example, a file-based interface in a UNIXy fashion? I'm grateful for your link to info on the `dalvikvm` command; this is very much along the lines of what I need. As for the last paragraph: doesn't your logic also show that there's no point in general purpose computing at all?

Comment: @gspr: "Wouldn't it be nicer to just make the API accessible through, for example, a file-based interface in a UNIXy fashion?" -- it would take several pages to explain all of the reasons why that's not practical. If you want a "UNIXy" programming model on a mobile device, try Tizen (formerly known as Maemo and various other names), or try the Canonical dual-boot environment, or something along those lines.

Comment: I can agree that it's not practical for the *consumer* (which, yes, is the vast majority of the millions of Android owners out there). But would it really cost that much to make available the API from a classical setting to those who want it? I mean, we already have the standard GNU toolchain; exposing the API would allow massive reuse of those tools. Oh and, I'm not saying this is practical for making "apps" -- I'm saying it's very, very practical for quick and dirty one-off tasks you'd solve with a BASH script in five minutes on a normal computer.

Comment: @gspr: "But would it really cost that much to make available to those who want it?" -- a couple dozen developer-years at minimum, I'd imagine (framework rewrites, security model overhaul, modified NDK toolchain, documentation, testing, etc.). You are welcome to gather a team that forks Android to implement this. Or, you are welcome to gather a team that develops a proof of concept, then proposes working with Google on this (see the `android-contrib` Google Group). If you are expecting Google to address this otherwise, prepare to be disappointed.

Comment: I've accepted the answer, the `dalvikvm` command is great. With it, I guess everything I need is at hand. Any further discussion should probably happen elsewhere (but just so we're clear: I'm not saying "Google should do so-and-so", rather, I'm expressing genuine surprise that a more UNIXy approach to the Android system isn't available to those of us for whom that saves a lot of time and effort).

Answer (score 3):

Here : [Running a shell script on android device using adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108004/running-bash-script-on-android-device-using-adb)

and : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en

and : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=537827

and : http://strawp.net/archive/recipe-for-a-decent-bash-shell-in-android/

and : http://digitaldumptruck.jotabout.com/?p=938

Comment: The first link is along the lines of what I wanted. I still cannot believe that that kind of stuff isn't on the first page of every Android development introduction out there. Anyway, I'll wait a bit with accepting, because even though the first link of your answer really helped me, I'm still hoping for some more fleshed-out information. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

From http://git-annex.branchable.com/design/assistant/blog/day_184__just_wanna_run_something/:

> While I already have Android "hello world" executables to try, I have
>   not yet been able to run them. Can't seem to find a directory I can
>   write to on the Asus Transformer, with a filesystem that supports the
>   +x bit. Do you really have to root Android just to run simple binaries? I'm crying inside.
>
> It seems that the blessed Android NDK way would involve making a Java
>   app, that pulls in a shared library that contains the native code. For
>   haskell, the library will need to contain a C shim that, probably,
>   calls an entry point to the Haskell runtime system. Once running, it
>   can use the FFI to communicate back to the Java side, probably. The
>   good news is that CJ van den Berg, who already saved my bacon once by
>   developing ghc-android, tells me he's hard at work on that very thing.

and some specific advices in the comments below:

> See http://kevinboone.net/android_nonroot.html for info on where in
>   the android filesystem you have write, exec ability.
>
> Basically you have these abilities in /data/local from adb shell (and
>   in debuggable app's folders using run-as with adb shell), and in
>   /data/data// for each app (for example the terminal emulator's
>   data dir when using the terminal emulator).
>
> ...

http://git-annex.branchable.com/design/assistant/blog/day_185__android_liftoff/:

> Thanks to hhm, who pointed me at [KBOX](http://kevinboone.net/kbox.html), I have verified that I can
>   build haskell programs that work on Android.

http://kevinboone.net/kbox.html:

> KBOX [...] gives you the terminal emulator, a
>   decent set of Linux utilities (supplied by busybox), ssh and rsync
>   clients and servers, and a few other things. In addition, there are a
>   number of add-on packages for expanded functionality.

Well, it's just about running an executable on Android, and not about writing an executable that would access Android API...

Answer (score 2):

> I can't seem to find any place on the net that explains how to simply make an ordinary program [...] with access to the Android API that can simply be run by SSHing into the phone and running it as a normal process.

An answer, translated from [a note by vitus-wagner](https://vitus-wagner.dreamwidth.org/1989724.html):

[Termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) is an advanced terminal emulator plus lots of Unix-like software with command-line interface (in packages managed by APT). Actually, not only CLI (command-line), but also GUI as well (though the GUI software not tried yet).

Unlike the way of the various popular "linux deploy" (which make something like a container, at least a chroot, with things installed into directories according to the traditional filesystem hierarchy), Termux seems to aim at integrating into the host system. For this purpose, it has a plugin, [Termux:api](https://termux.com/add-on-api.html) which is able to do a lot of interaction with the system: open a file in a native Android app, send an sms, take a picture with the camera, or even say something by means of the system TTS engine.

There are many more addons -- see [wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Main_Page).

(A side note. An integration like that could be expected--if not from MSYS--from GnuWin32, but there is nothing close to Termux under Windows w.r.t. the degree of integration.

However, for some strange reason, people are asking much more about how to make it more "Linux-like" on the forum, rather than how to use it effectively to solve smartphone-specific tasks...)

[A toolkit for cross-compilation](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/) is available, so that one can try to package his favorite software.

Actually, it is able to do compilation locally on the device, but it seems not to be able to make a package locally.

Some things to know:

1. One needs [Hacker's keyboard](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard/) or something similar. One can't live here without Esc, Tab, Control. Or one could try to learn the [Touch Keyboard](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Touch_Keyboard).
2. `vim` ran with an encoding different from utf-8, and the Russian letters were displayed incorrectly. So, `set encoding=utf-8` had to be written in `.vimrc`.
3. ssh to another computer at home couldn't login. The reason was simple: it used the username `u0_a95` instead of one's usual username. (One can write `User your_username` in `.ssh/config` to permanently "fix" it.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing a research on [XDA-Developers board](http://forum.xda-developers.com)

Comment: Thanks, but I refuse to believe that this isn't thoroughly documented somewhere. I mean, what kind of crazy idea is it to begin with fancy-schmancy GUI stuff before doing basics such as a terminal-based "Hello, world"?